# Select some field inside a Json input witch is several layer in it

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, serialization, deserialization, response

I get a response witch is like bellow:

```
  {
  "status": 1,
  "result": {
  "id": "28",
  "userName": "Sara",
  "city": "177",
  "cityName": "sari",
  "address": "sadr ave...",
  "documents": [
  {
    "documentTypeId": "3",
    "fileName": "a.jpg",
    "fileType": "image/jpeg",
    "content": "aaaa"
  },
  {
    "documentTypeId": "2",
    "fileName": "b.jpg",
    "fileType": "image/jpeg",
    "content": "aaa"
      }
    ]
  }
```

}

I want to have response Be like above but with out "content" so
I define the output properties like bellow :

```
        public class Response
    {
        public int status { get; set; }
        public List<result> result { get; set; }
     }

public class result
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public int city { get; set; }
        public string cityName { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public List<documents> documents { get; set; }
    }


    public class documents
    {
        public int documentTypeId { get; set; }
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        public string fileType { get; set; }
    }
```

I do not want to get "content" so I eliminate it  In document class
but my response is just like bellow :

```
  {"status":1,"result":[]}
```

what can I do to get response like above with out content :
my code to get response is like bellow :

```
bodyRequest.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { caseId = caseId }), 
Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var responseApi = Client.PostAsync(baseAddress, bodyRequest.Content, 
 new System.Threading.CancellationToken(false)).Result;
 if (responseApi.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
     {
         ResponseText = responseApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
         var res = jss.Deserialize<ApiResponse>(ResponseText);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct class must be the same as bellow :

```
 public class Response
 {
     public int status { get; set; }
     public Result result { get; set; }
 }

 public class Result
 {
     public string id { get; set; }
     public string userName { get; set; }
     public string city { get; set; }
     public string cityName { get; set; }
     public string address { get; set; }
     public Document[] documents { get; set; }
 }

 public class Document
 {
     public string documentTypeId { get; set; }
     public string fileName { get; set; }
     public string fileType { get; set; }
     [JsonIgnore]
     public string content { get; set; }
 }
```